# Splitting Up Title in Beamer

Tags: beamer

I'm trying to make a beamer presentation for a talk. The title of the talk is fairly long. I want to figure out how to make sure only the last part of the title is displayed footer of the slide. I attempted to use the \subtitle command, but it only forced the beginning of the title to shift down. Is there anyway to fix this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
    \begin{frame}<beamer>
        \frametitle{Roadmap}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection]
    \end{frame}
}




\subtitle{Some results on the notion of}
\title{Independence on Simple Theories}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\end{document}
```

This produces "Independence on Simple Theories" in bigger letters followed by "Some results on the notion of" by smaller letters, but I want, "Some results on the notion of" by smaller letters followed by "Independence on Simple Theories". This is one fix for my problem, but any other solutions to make the footer always show "Independence on Simple Theories" in the footer will also work.

Comment: `\title[Independence on Simple Theories]{Some results on the notion of Independence on Simple Theories}`

Comment: @MikeRenfro: Thank you. That was exactly what I was looking for.